# How do we get the theme of an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, themes

I am trying to detect the theme used for an activity but so far I am only able to find that out for the entire application? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just call the method getTheme() in your activity. For example.

```
public class MainActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Theme theme = this.getTheme();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

My first thought would be [ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#getTheme%28%29), since `Activity` extends `ContextThemeWrapper`